# How to use external class in Workflow Activity in .NET?

Tags: c#, types, workflow-foundation, class-library

I have a class defined in a class library:

```
namespace TestLib
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public static void Test() { }
    }
}
```

I also have an `Activity` defined in a `XAML` file. Now I want to use `InvokeMethod` activity inside that activity to call static method inside the class, but the debugger throws runtime exception which says:

`"Could not load file or assembly 'TestLib, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."`

The class library is properly referenced and I can see that in XAML source, too.
If I include this class into the source, it works fine.

What is the correct way to use external types in workflows and what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

UPDATE:

Recreating this case is very simple.

Create a `Class Library` project named `TestLib` and add the above `TestClass`.

Create an `Activity Library` project and rename main activity to `TestActivity`. Add reference to `TestLib`. Add one `Sequence` activity with an `InvokeMethod` activity inside, and use it to call method `TestClass.Test`. This is `XAML` code:

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap sap2010 sads" x:Class="WorkflowSimpleTest.TestActivity" sap2010:ExpressionActivityEditor.ExpressionActivityEditor="C#" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="WorkflowSimpleTest.Activity1_1"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 xmlns:sads="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/debugger"
 xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation"
 xmlns:sap2010="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/presentation"
 xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:sco="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:t="clr-namespace:TestLib;assembly=TestLib"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation>
    <sco:Collection x:TypeArguments="x:String">
      <x:String>System</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Collections.Generic</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Data</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Linq</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Text</x:String>
    </sco:Collection>
  </TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation>
  <TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation>
    <sco:Collection x:TypeArguments="AssemblyReference">
      <AssemblyReference>Microsoft.CSharp</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Activities</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Core</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Data</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Runtime.Serialization</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.ServiceModel</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.ServiceModel.Activities</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Xaml</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Xml</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Xml.Linq</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>mscorlib</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>TestLib</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>WorkflowSimpleTest</AssemblyReference>
    </sco:Collection>
  </TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation>
  <Sequence sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Sequence_1">
    <InvokeMethod sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="InvokeMethod_1" MethodName="Test" TargetType="t:TestClass" />
    <WriteLine sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="WriteLine_1" Text="End activity." />
    <sads:DebugSymbol.Symbol>d1dEOlxFbHZlZGluXFByb2plY3RzXEF1dG9tYXRpb24mQklcc291cmNlXFNFQ1VSSVRBU1xXb3JrZm9sd1NpbXBsZVRlc3RcVGVzdEFjdGl2aXR5LnhhbWwEJgMqDgIBAScFJ3ECAQQoBShVAgECKEMoUgIBAw==</sads:DebugSymbol.Symbol>
  </Sequence>
  <sap2010:WorkflowViewState.ViewStateManager>
    <sap2010:ViewStateManager>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="InvokeMethod_1" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="218,130" />
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="WriteLine_1" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="218,62" />
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="Sequence_1" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="240,356">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="WorkfolwSimpleTest.Activity1_1" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="280,436" />
    </sap2010:ViewStateManager>
  </sap2010:WorkflowViewState.ViewStateManager>
</Activity>
```

Create a console application and execute the workflow using this code:

```
Dictionary<string, object> vars = new Dictionary<string, object>() { };
WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new TestActivity(), vars);
wfApp.Completed += delegate (WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Completed.");
};
wfApp.Idle += delegate (WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Idle.");
};
wfApp.Run();
```

The application should throw runtime exception.

Comment: Is it possible that you add more code, probably, your use of `InvokeMethod` and other important stuff?

Comment: @J.Pichardo I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was exactly as it stated. Apparently from adding a reference to the library in the `Workflow Library` project, I should add a reference in the host project as well.